How to properly exclude specific files from .gitignore
I'm trying to get a .gitignore working in wordpress. I want to exclude the uploads files and the temporary plugin upgrade files, but not ignore the .htaccess and index.html static files in those directories (or any other sub directories).
I tried:
# Uploads
/wp-content/uploads/*

# temp backup
/wp-content/upgrade-temp-backup/

# include any htaccess files or static indexes
!**/.htaccess
!**/index.html`

but it is still saying the .htaccess and index files under wp-content are ignored when I try to 'add' them to git.
Can anyone help me out with whatever I'm missing here?
I also tried exclusions directly to the files effected and got the same result.  e.g.
!/wp-content/uploads/woocommerce_uploads/.htaccess
!/wp-content/uploads/woocommerce_uploads/index.html
!/wp-content/uploads/wc-logs/.htaccess
!/wp-content/uploads/wc-logs/index.html`


Read this answer. It could reveal you why it does not work and how to make it work.

I know how to 'force' add. I don't want to force add.  Also, I'm not trying to 'allow' any file under that folder. I only want to allow specific files in that folder tree. Which is what I thought the above was supposed to be doing - but it doesn't seem to work.

As it says in the doc, It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded. . So, you have to force-add.
